# How do I add an external toolkit to vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

I am sorry as this is such a beginner question. But I have been messing around with LUA in vscode and was going to add a GUI toolkit (namely wxlua) and start learning that too. My only problem is that I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add something that isn't an in the extensions marketplace.

If it is at all relevant, the project is currently a blank main.lua file, a launch.json file that looks like this:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lua",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.lua.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I am using the lua extension luadebug by actboy168.

After spending hours googling solution I am honestly just entirely lost as to where to even start with this, which I am aware is likely a huge oversight on my part since this is like a pre-beginner task.